# Fill in new page with JavaScript variables from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript, and I want to create one html file with input fields and some buttons. When users fill in all the data and select their buttons, they press submit button which will open new "result.html" page where I want to storage some variables. This page should have its own design and present results of their action.

Can you give me an advice how to do this properly. I tried with the code below but witn no success.

**quick.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="submit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 25px;"><input type="text" id="name"></div>
    <div style="height: 25px;"><input type="text" id="age"></div>

    <div><input type="submit" id="p11" value="1" onClick="add1();"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" id="p12" value="2" onClick="add1();"></div><br /><br />
    <div><input type="submit" id="p21" value="1" onClick="add3();"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" id="p22" value="2" onClick="add4();"></div><br /><br />

    <div id="button"> 
    <input type="submit" id="calculate" value="CALCULATE" onClick="run();input();wopen();">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**submit.js**

```
var p1 = 0;
var p2 = 0;

function add1() {
    p1 = 1; return p1;}
function add2() {
    p1 = 2; return p1;}
function add3() {
    p2 = 1; return p2;}
function add4() {
    p2 = 2; return p2;}

function run() {
    sum = p1+p2;}

function input() {
    inp1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
    inp2 = document.getElementById("age").value;
    myName = "My name is: " + inp1 + '<br />';
    myAge = "My age is: " + inp2 + '<br />';}

function wopen() {
    window.open("result.html","_blank");}
```

**result.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="submit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="number"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = ("The name: " + myName);
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = ("The name: " + myName);
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = ("The sum of numbers: " + sum);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

```
function input() {
    inp1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
    localStorage.setItem('myName', inp1);
}
```

**In result.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('myName');
</script>
```

Comment: You could also use cookies, but I'm sure someone will say that's a bad idea. My preferred method is localStorage, but remember ancient web browsers (IE7) do not like localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a new window/tab for the result page, your original page is still accessible through the opener object.

Steps:
1. Load a new Html like result.html into the new window
2. In the body onload event, call a function which will access those fields like below:

```
var v1 = window.opener.document.getElementById('thatid').value;
```